# Adding dynamic fields in Reactive with the dictionary and push them into existing FormControl

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to dynamically load some fields into my reactive form. Here  are the fields, I have (**please note that these fields change depending on the selection, so I can't hardcode them**):

```
fields = [{  df_id: 48,
              df_name: "Phone Number",
              df_type: "text",
              df_options: "None",
              df_default: "None"
              },
              {
              df_id: 49,
              df_name: "Evaluering",
              df_type: "dropdown",
              df_options: ["Option1","Option2","Option3"],
              df_default: "None",
              }];
```

Here is what I tried in the typescript:

```
this.testForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      start_date: ['', Validators.required],
      end_date: ['', Validators.required],
      call_direction: ['', Validators.required],
      items: this.formBuilder.array([])
    })


this.fields.forEach((x:any) => {
            this.testForm.addControl(x.df_name, new FormControl('',Validators.required));
          });
```

The **HTML** file looks the like following:

```
<div class="row pt-2" *ngFor="let field of fields">
   <div class="col-4 d-flex align-items-center 13required">{{field.df_name}}&nbsp;  </div>
   <div class="col-6">
      <mat-form-field *ngIf="field.df_type == 'text'"  appearance="outline">
         <input matInput [type]="field.df_type" [formControlName]="field.df_name"  required/>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field *ngIf="field.df_type == 'dropdown'"  appearance="outline">
         <mat-select [formControlName]="field.df_name" placeholder="">
            <mat-option
            [value]="option"
            *ngFor="let option of field.df_options"
            >
            {{ option }}
            </mat-option>
         </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
   </div>
</div>
```

**This works! However, the form values are not formatted to my liking, for example,**

#### Currently it looks like:

```
{
"start_date":"2021-08-01",
 "end_date" : "2021-08-31",
 "call_direction": "Both",
 "items": [],
 "Phone Number": "3174",
 "Evaluering": "Option1"
}
```

### what I would like is to push them into `items`:

```
{
"start_date":"2021-08-01",
 "end_date" : "2021-08-31",
 "call_direction": "Both",
 "items": [{"Phone Number": "3174", "Evaluering": "Option1"}],
}
```

I checked the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54521848/how-to-add-input-fields-dynamically-in-angular-6) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449195/dynamically-add-a-set-of-fields-to-a-reactive-form), which uses the `FormArray` and `FormGroup` but I couldn't get it working with my limited knowledge of Angular and typescript. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: This answer if to create the formArray with the FormGroup, you should change the .html to mannage a FormArray

Where you're adding the FormControls?

As always you use a FormArray, declare a getter of the formArray

```
get itemsArray(){
   return this.fields.get('items') as FormArray;
}
```

And I imagine it's good to have a function that return the FormGroup

```
createGroup(fields:any[]){
    //create a FormGroup Empty
    const group=new FormGroup({});

    //add the FormControl to the group
    fields.forEach((x:any) => {
            group.addControl(x.df_name, new FormControl('',Validators.required));
          });
     return group;
}
```

So you can use

```
this.testForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      start_date: ['', Validators.required],
      end_date: ['', Validators.required],
      call_direction: ['', Validators.required],
      items: this.formBuilder.array([this.createGroup(this.fields)])
    })

//or to adding a new FormGroup to the array
this.itemsArray.push(this.createGroup(this.fields))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, just you need to add the new `control` to the `FormArray` field not to the form controls directly like the following:

```js
this.fields.forEach((x: any) => {
  (this.eyeForm.controls.get('items') as FormArray).controls.push(
    new FormControl(x.df_name, Validators.required)
  );
});
```

Then you need to wrap your provided template with `formGroup` and `formArrayName`, besides assigning the `formControlName` to the index of the control, not to the name:

```html
<div [formGroup]="eyeForm">
  <div formArrayName="items">
    <div class="row pt-2" *ngFor="let field of fields; let i = index">
      <div class="col-4 d-flex align-items-center 13required">
        {{ field.df_name }}&nbsp;
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="field.df_type == 'text'" appearance="outline">
          <input
            matInput
            [type]="field.df_type"
            [formControlName]="i"
            required
          />
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field
          *ngIf="field.df_type == 'dropdown'"
          appearance="outline"
        >
          <mat-select [formControlName]="i" placeholder="">
            <mat-option
              [value]="option"
              *ngFor="let option of field.df_options"
            >
              {{ option }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer. I tried but there is one problem. I get the following in the item `items: (3) ["Phone Number", "Evaluering", "Methode"]`. It is storing things like an array without values. One change I made  `eyeForm.controls.get('items') as FormArray)` to eyeForm.controls['items'] as FormArray). Can you perhaps stackblitz it? or see what's wrong. Also, phone number gets "Phone Number" value default in the UI.